# firebaseui: angular error after building the application

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I am developing an angular application. The application employs various firebase services, including Authentication.
I am also using firebaseui for the login activities.

When I am testing the application via `ng serve`, everything works fine and as expected. But when I'm deploying the built application to firebase hosting, I get the following error:

```
npm.js:73 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Promise' of undefined
    at da (npm.js:73)
    at npm.js:74
    at npm.js:425
    at Object../node_modules/firebaseui/dist/npm.js (npm.js:425)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:83)
    at Module../src/app/login/login.component.ts (main-es2015.js:277)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:83)
    at Module../src/app/login/login.module.ts (login.component.ts:10)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:83)
    at Module../src/app/app.module.ts (app.component.ts:8)
```

I already figured out, that the issue is clearly with firebaseui, but I can't find the reason why everything works as expected locally via `ng serve` and only the built application causes the error.

Did anyone of you already had a similar issue and maybe a way to solve it?

Btw, I am using the following versions of relevant dependencies:

```
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.0.1",
    "@angular/core": "~8.0.1",
    "@angular/fire": "^5.2.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.0.1",
    "@angular/router": "~8.0.1",
    "firebase": "^6.2.2",
    "firebaseui": "^4.0.0"
```

And the login component, where I actually call firebaseui:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import * as firebaseui from 'firebaseui';
import {AngularFireAuth} from '@angular/fire/auth';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private auth: AngularFireAuth) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    const uiConfig = {
      signInSuccessUrl: '/app',
      signInOptions: [
        'google.com',
        'github.com',
        'facebook.com',
        'password'
      ],
      tosUrl: '',
      privacyPolicyUrl: ''
    };
    const ui = new firebaseui.auth.AuthUI(this.auth.auth);
    ui.start('#firebaseui-auth-container', uiConfig);
  }

}
```

Thanks in advance!